# How do I run an executable using Lua?

Tags: lua, executable

I have an executable I want to run using Lua ... how do I do this?

Can't seem to find any documentation anywhere about this.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use Lua's native 'execute' command.

Example:

```
os.execute("c:\\temp\\program.exe")
```

Sources: [Lua Guide / os.execute](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.execute)

Comment: Nearly double-posted with interjay! Ha! At least we both said the same thing! Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for a clear and simple example that demonstrates the concept in a way that can be easily grasped immediately upon inspection.

Answer (score 23):

If you need the output of the program, use [`io.popen`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.popen)

Answer (score 6):

For someone who need using io.popen

```
local openPop = assert(io.popen('/bin/ls -la', 'r'))
local output = openPop:read('*all')
openPop:close()
print(output) -- > Prints the output of the command.
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`os.execute`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.execute).