# How Can I Execute a Non-Lua File From a Lua Script?

Tags: lua

I have a Lua script and I want to execute a batch file from within this file; how can I do this?

I've seen examples as follows that I thought could do this but in retrospect I am probably misunderstanding their purpose:

```
os.execute('C:\\tmp\\MyFile.bat')
```

or

```
local handle = io.open('C:\\tmp\\MyFile.bat')
handle:close()
```

I believe this question has been asked and answered before: [How do I run an executable using Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829404/how-do-i-run-an-executable-using-lua)

However my code is failing; I'm not sure why. Is there a library I need to load for 'os' for example?

When I try and run this code I get the following error:

"attempt to index a nil value"

Comment: What about those examples is not working for you? If you are getting errors from either of them please include those.

Comment: I added it to the post; sorry I left that out.

Comment: I assume that's for the second (`io.open`) case? That just means `io.open` didn't return a handle, which means something failed. In that case `io.open` returns a second error value. `local handle, err = io.open(...)` if not handle then print(err) else handle:close() end`.

Comment: Also `io.open` opens the file for reading/writing. It doesn't execute anything. Use `os.execute` or `io.popen` for executing processes.

Comment: I have tried io.popen and os.execute and it's as if io/os are not visible; is there a library I must load?

Comment: Not if you're using the command line. How are you running the code?

Comment: Paste the __entire__ stack traceback of error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `os.execute[[yourFile.bat]]` when opening a batch file.
More information for this [here](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2003-05/msg00290.html)