# Binding custom node addon to lua with extentions

Tags: node.js, lua

I have a large collection of asynchronous functions that I have in nodejs code that I would like to expose to lua.  The basic idea is that I would like to execute lua scripts and allow those scripts to call back into some of my  nodejs code, as well as asynchronously return a value from an executed lua script,

In this example `myCustomNodejsAddon` would be a custom addon that I write that knows how to bind lua and run lua scripts.  One outstanding question is how do I asynchronously return a value from a lua script?

Has anyone done something like this before?  I would be very interested in any pointers, thoughts, examples.

EDIT with better example:

```
-- user written lua script
getUser(1, function(err, user)
   if err then
      print('Error', err)
   else
      print('Found user with id', user.id)
      return ''
   end
end)
```

```js
/*Create object with mapping of async functions*/
var callbacks = {
   "getUser": function(userId, cb) {
      db.Users.fetchById(userId).then(function(user) {
         cb(null, user);
      }, function(err) {
         cb(err, null);
      }
   }
};
myCustomNodejsAddon.provideCallbacks(callbacks);

/* user written lua script has been stored into `scriptSrc` variable */
myCustomNodejsAddon.execute(scriptSrc, function(returnValueOfScript) {
   console.log('done running user script: ', retrunValueOfScript);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

More than one approaches to this problem comes to my mind.

The first would be to create a nodejs script that once executed read the program command line arguments or input stream and execute the code indicated by this channel and stream the response back in JSON format for example. This is the less invasive way of doing this. The script would be something like:

```
if(require.main === module){
   // asume first argument to be the source module for the function of iterest
   var mod = require(process.argv[2]);
   var fnc = mod[process.argv[3]];

   args = process.argv.slice(4);

   // by convention the last argument is a callback function
   args.push(function(){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments));
       process.exit();
   })

   fnc.apply(null, args);
}
```

An example usage will be:

```
$ node my-script.js fs readdir /some/path
```

This will respond with something like [null, ['file1', 'file2']] acording with the files on `/some/path`. Then you can create a lua module that invoque node with this script and pass the parameters according with the functions you want to call.

Comment: How would this handle the `async` part of the question? What does the lua side of this process look like?

Comment: This will handle the async part of the question in the sense that the Nodejs process will only write to the output stream once the callback is called. Thus producing results asyncronically. There is some time i don't use Lua, so i'm not sure howto implement that part

Comment: May be you can use the answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829404/how-do-i-run-an-executable-using-lua

Comment: @yeiniel while your proposal is cleaver, I need the async and closure provided by nodejs. The example I gave is maybe over-simplified, but the structure of it needs to be preserved for my much more complicated requirements to be satisfied.

Comment: I understand your point @EToreo but without more details i provide you with code that probably handle the case you expose in your lua code and it handle it supporting the async nature of Nodejs. May be you can provide a concrete example in order to provide a better answer.

Comment: I have tried to update the example and explanation with a more concrete example and thoughts.  @yeiniel, does that help?

Comment: Sorry i miss the part "as well as asynchronously return a value from an executed lua script". I think you will need to resort to c++ to compile a nodejs executable with the lua interpreter embedded for that. Because the solution i propose above is for the case of running both interpreters separated and the lua interpreter in a role of master.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  How would a custom compile of nodejs help more than a custom nodejs addon?  Both are c++ and can embed lua.