# Can call Java JAR file in LUA scripting language?

Tags: java, lua

Is it possible to call Java JAR files from LUA script?
I wrote JAVA application that doesn't possible to write it in LUA language, is it possible to execute it in LUA?

Comment: Does invoking `java -jar` as just a normal executable work for you? If so, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829404/how-do-i-run-an-executable-using-lua

Comment: You run a system command that starts a JVM and runs your java code.

Comment: i am executing lua script in kong and i want to call a jar file with 30 classes, thus i have to call this jar filein lua script instead of convert java code to lua.

Comment: @GhostCat how can i run system command? as https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076640/yshavit  mention i can run executable, but i want to run jar file.

Comment: The executable named `java` can run jar files (search online for more details).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file ... but honestly: could it be that you are simply overburdening yourself? You want to do really basic stuff, with many many resources/tutorials/... explaining them, but yet  you are asking such questions? What I mean is: when you already wrote a java application, how can you *not* know how to run that?